# I can't format my hard drive with Gparted

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

My external hard disk isn't readable so I have tried to format it with gparted but when it try to do it it gives me this massege.

> No partition table found on device /dev/sdb
>
> /dev/sdb:unrecognised disk lable

Here are pictures of the situation:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like your disk is broken.

Comment: It is not broken.

Comment: If it isn't broken, why isn't it readable?

Comment: I don't know why

Comment: Did you use this as a Linux installer which may have used dd? That creates a hybrid drive which is not partitioned and then causes issues. If that is case often just zeroing out first sector(s) so drive can then be partitioned.  What does this show? `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb` ?  Post output above in question, and maintain formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Input/output errors are usually caused by hardware problems.  The hardware problem can be as simple as a loose cable, or as serious as failing hard disk drive.

When the error occurs you can open a terminal window and enter the `dmesg` command to learn more details.

You might also consider using `gsmartcontrol` to view the disk device health statistics to see if the drive is failing.

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: What didn't work?  Did you try installing/running `gsmartcontrol`?  `sudo apt install gsmartcontrol` to install and `sudo gsmartcontrol` to run.

Comment: Yes i Did, installed it

Comment: Did you look through the content of the various tabs in `gsmartcontrol` to see if there are any indications of drive failure?  When my hard drives begin to fail they usually start showing a non-zero value for `Reallocated_Sector_Ct`.